# how do I append an stdClass Object

Tags: php, stdclass

I have an stdClass Object like generated by joomla like this

```
$db->setQuery($sql);
$schoollist = $db->loadObjectList();
```

And the $schoollist variable contains the following stdClass Objects

```
stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 [col1] => blabla [col2] => 5 [col3] => 208 ) 
stdClass Object ( [id] => 2 [col1] => test1 [col2] => 1 [col3] => 52 )
```

and I need to add another "column" after the query as [col4] => dsdads , so the result will be like this

```
stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 [col1] => blabla [col2] => 5 [col3] => 208 [col4] => 208) 
stdClass Object ( [id] => 2 [col1] => test1 [col2] => 1 [col3] => 52 [col4] => 208)
```

how can I do this?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Simply set a new field:

```
$object->col4 = $value;
```

If you need dynamic field names:

```
$object->$fieldName = $value;
```

Answer (score 13):

RE dynamic field names.

These should be defined as such.

```
$object->{$fieldName} = $value;
```